# Asset-Pipeline doesn't exclude files

Tags: grails, gradle, asset-pipeline

I'm not able to exclued certain files in a Grails 3, Gradle Multimodule-Project. The configuration is exactly as discribed in the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html).

In `project\module\grails-app\conf\application.groovy` I have the exclution defined: `grails.assets.plugin."module-plugin".excludes =  ["**/*.md"]`

Then I call on module level `../gradlew assetClean` and `../gradlew assetCompile`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined it in `project/build.gradle`, not in `project/module/grails-app/conf/application.groovy`.

Like this it works!